# A country riddle

Tags: riddle, word

A riddle I made up while bored. Please follow the steps of the riddle below:

> Start with the name of a specific country . . .
>
> If you lowercase the name of this country . . .
>
> And reverse the order of the letters . . .
>
> Then follow the steps below to answer the final question.
>
> Word 1: Change the third letter to 'u'.
>
> This is related to the innermost being.
>
> Word 2: Add an 'h' behind the first letter.
>
> The word you should get is related to aquatic animals.

Now answer these two questions:

- **What is the country?**
- **What is the animal at the [Insert Word 1 here] of a [Insert Word 2 here]?**

Hint Below

> It is as four letter country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The country is

> **LAOS**!

---

Following the instructions:

> LAOS -> laos
> laos <-> soal
> so<strike>a</strike>l -> **soul**
> s(h)oal -> **shoal**

We see that

> The 'soul' is the innermost being, and you have a 'shoal' of fish

So the final question and answer:

> What is the animal at the **soul** of a **shoal**?
>
> A **FISH**!